# flash preloader printing problem

Tags: flash, actionscript, preloader

I've got a flash movie with preloader. Preloader Event.COMPLETE listener looks like this

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
stage.addChild(loader.content);
parent.removeChild(this);
```

The problem is that when I try to print the movie that was loaded by it, preloader is printed instead. Why can this be happening?

Answer (score 0):

THis is enough weird style `parent.removeChild(this);` but I need a more full code to see what are you doing there.